# Check my solution of no.2 please

Tags: number-theory, problem-solving

1.Show that the closest integer to $(2 + \sqrt{5})^{2017} -2^{2018}$  is divisible by $2017$. (Solved)

2.Suppose that $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers and that for some integer $2 \leq n$, $a^n + b^n = c^n$

Let $k$ be an integer with $1 \leq k <n$. Prove that there is triangle with side length $a^k,b^k,c^k$

My $Sol$ of 2) $f(n)=a^n +b^n ,g(n)=c^n, 
f(n)-g(n) =h(n)=0, h'(n)=a^n log(a) + b^n log(b) - c^n log(c)$. $h'(n)$ is decreasing function, so by $k<n,h(k)=a^k+b^k-c^k>0 =h(n) $.

($a,b<c$ is trivial)

This proof is work?

Comment: How did you try in order to solve it?

Comment: @EugenCovaci  in 1. I think like that (2^2017+sqrt{5}^2017+2017(........) -2^2018)   and in 2. I have no idea in now

Comment: @EugenCovaci I upload my solution of 2 but it is right?

Comment: @ToniMhax umm..... you talk about my proof of number 2 or?

Comment: It isn't right as it is not rigourous, you need to PROVE it is decreasing. (hell). Good day

Comment: I've deleted my comment clearly it is faulty. I talk about 2

Answer (score 4):

**Hint for 1**. $(2+\sqrt{5})^{2017}+(2-\sqrt{5})^{2017}$ is an integer and $(2-\sqrt{5})^{2017}$ is very small.

By setting $a_n=(2+\sqrt{5})^n+(2-\sqrt{5})^n$ we have $a_0=2, a_1=4$ and $a_{n+2}=4 a_{n+1}+a_n$.

$2017$ is a prime and $5$ is not a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{2017}$. By considering $\mathbb{F}_{2017}[x]/(x^2-4x-1)\simeq\mathbb{F}_{2017^2}$ and by taking $\alpha$ as a root of $x^2-4x-1$, by Vieta's Theorem and Frobenius map $x\to x^{2017}$ we get $\alpha+\alpha^p = \alpha^p+\alpha^{p^2}=4$.

It follows that
$$(2+\sqrt{5})^{2017}+(2-\sqrt{5})^{2017}-2^{2018}\equiv 4-4\equiv\color{red}{0}\pmod{2017}.$$

Comment: Can you please tell me where can I learn about this stuff you wrote. I don' t understand anything. Why do you consider polynomials here and what does this Frobenius map do? Thank you.